Delete an ID linked to a button from the database
How would I delete the data linked to the relevant ID when the trash can button is pressed? 
I have tried using thrash but that does not seem to work.
Unless, if there is a way to do it with thrash that I may not know of. But from my understanding, thrash is completely useless in this situation.
<?php

require_once 'connection.php';
require_once 'count.php';  


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th scope="row">' . $row["id"] . '</th>';
        echo '<td><img src="' . $row["image_url"] . '" class="user-photo" alt="' . $row["name"] . ' Photo">' . $row["name"] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row["date"] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row["role"] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><i class="fa-solid fa-circle" style="color: ' . $row["status_color"] . ';"> </i> ' . $row["status"] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><button>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-pen" style="color: #0a0a0a;"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="deleteBtn" data-id="<?php echo $row["id"];">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash" style="color: #48b180;"></i>
                </button>
            </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan='6'>0 sonuç</td></tr>";
}
$conn->close();
?>

<?php
require_once 'connection.php'; 

function urunSilme($id) {
    global $conn; 

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $id);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM formbilgileri WHERE id='$id'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Veri başarıyla silindi";
    } else {
        echo "Silme işlemi başarısız: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '') {
    urunSilme($_GET['id']);
} else {
    echo "Geçersiz ID değeri";
}
?>

function deleteRow(id) {
    if (confirm("Bu satırı silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?")) {
        window.location.href = "delete.php?id=" + id; // Silme işlemini gerçekleştirecek olan PHP dosyanızın adını ve yolunu buraya yazınız
    }
}


<?php echo $row["id"];"> is wrong where it is. It's inside PHP already so no need to <?php echo and it would be missing ?> to close it. I'd bet there's no id in any of those data-id attributes - which you could've checked by inspecting the element

What is deleteRow(id) for? You never call it. Why use a <button> instead of a simple <a href> to the page, passing the id?

I solved it by editing the code like this              echo '<button class="deleteBtn" onclick="deleteRow(' . $row['id'] . ')">';         echo '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash" style="color: #48b180;"></i>';

Glad you fixed it...but: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, because comments cannot be searched, and you cannot get reputation points for them. Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. The Can I answer my own question? and [answer] articles from the help centre are also relevant. Thanks.

P.S. Warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the mysqli documentation and this: How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP? . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Also please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); before your mysqli_connect() (or new mysqli()) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident. In a live environment you should always log all PHP errors to a file.

BTW you don't really need JavaScript for this. You could just replace the button with <a class="deleteBtn" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash" style="color: #48b180;"></i></a>

You'd still need JS for the confirm(...) though

@brombeer good point, which I concede
